# Android SupportMapFragment does not load map on kitkat devices

Tags: android, google-maps

I am integrating the google maps into my app and it does not work in kitkat devices but works fine with lollipop versions. My code is :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMap();
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

and i am getting the following error message for kitkat devices.

```
getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33531689/4625829) before?

Comment: Try updating google map and other application related to maps in that device such as "Google" , "Maps" and other system apps

Comment: getMapAsync(this) instead of getMap()

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your manifest.xml file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and extent your activity with FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was in my android device i just created a account in maps and next thing was that just opened my app and it started working, :)